# Min, Max of an Int variable c++

Tags: c++, max, game-development, min

I'm currently following the "Udemy C++ Fundamentals Game Programming For Beginners" and I'm trying to challenge myself by adding additional functionality to each project you build.

As it stands, each time the player jumps they have the same velocity and I'd like to add a held key press to vary each jump's height.

I'd like the minimum amount of velocity to be -15, with the max velocity to be -22. The variable in question is "jumpVelocity".

Is the best/most efficient way to go about this a clamp? If not, I'm open to suggestions.

Here is the script for context with the highlighted areas, TiA!

```
#include <raylib.h>

int main()
{
    //Window dimensions.
    const int windowWidth{512};
    const int windowHeight{380};

    //Initialise window.
    InitWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "Alex's Dapper Game");

    //Gravity (pixels/frame)/frame.
    const int gravity{1};
    int jumpVelocity{-15}; <----------------------- I WANT TO USE A MIN AND MAX INT HERE.

    //Rectangle dimensions.
    const int rectWidth{50};
    const int rectHeight{80};
    bool isInAir{false};

    //Rectangle properties.
    float posX{(windowWidth * .5) - (rectWidth * .5)};
    int posY{windowHeight - rectHeight};
    int rectVelocity{0};

    //Window FPS.
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    while (!WindowShouldClose())
    {
        //Start drawing.
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(WHITE);

        //Ground check.
        if (posY >= (windowHeight - rectHeight))
        {
            //Rect on ground
            rectVelocity = 0;
            isInAir = false;
        }
        else
        {
        //Rectangle in air, apply gravity.
        jumpVelocity = -15;
        rectVelocity += gravity;
        isInAir = true;
        }

        if(IsKeyDown(KEY_SPACE))
        {
            jumpVelocity += 1; <--------------------------- I WANT TO INCREASE FROM -15 TO -25 DEPENDING ON THE KEY HOLD.
        }

        //Jump
        if (IsKeyReleased(KEY_SPACE) && (!isInAir))
        {
            rectVelocity += jumpVelocity;
        }

        //Update position.
        posY += rectVelocity;

        DrawRectangle(posX, posY, rectWidth, rectHeight, BLUE);

        //Stop drawing.
        EndDrawing();
    }
    
    // Close the window.
    CloseWindow();
}
```

Comment: *Is the best/most efficient way to go about this a clamp?* -- Honestly, I don't think that this is anything to be concerned about.  You are doing a simple integer-based calculation -- by the time the compiler optimizes the code, no matter what you do, this will result in no difference in the performance.  You should be concerned with how to optimize based on picking the right algorithms and/or data structure(s), not micro-optimizations such as the one you are concerned with.

Comment: -15 is bigger than -22. Are you asking how to randomly pick a number between -22 and -15?

Comment: Thanks. I come from UE and Blueprints which is already a less efficient way than code, so efficiency has always been high on my list of priorities.

Comment: The problem it's not guaranteed that your code optimization will change actual performance since the compiler already is very good at optimizing this in the first place. You may spend weeks of work trying to save 5 nano seconds only to find out that the compiler optimized it already and there is nothing left to save.

Comment: C++ is going to be faster than you can possibly fathom for trivial operations like clamp. In many cases, this operation will be complete before the light from your screen travels the short distance to your eyes.

Comment: It is best to focus on clean correct code first and worry about optimization later once you can profile so you know where the hotspots are. The first draft may not survive anyway and its only purpose may be to help you learn what you really need for the final solution. Spending time optimizing something you throw away is wasteful. The nice thing about code is it's pretty easy to refactor versus something like blueprints that can be a headache to rearrange.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman it was just the way the course showed. What is the difference between the 2 methods? Thanks

Comment: @Caleth I didn't say that either were bigger, just that they are 2 ends of my velocity bounds. I want to start at -15 as it is the smallest jump possible and go to -22 as it is the highest jump possible.

Comment: So, what do I need to do to the jumpVelocity int so that I can have it's min bounds be -15 and max bounds be -22? Thanks

Comment: Well first off you'll need to *subtract* from -15 to go towards -22, because like I said, -15 is bigger than -22

Comment: @Caleth The "IsKeyDown(KEY_SPACE)" section does that. The only problem is that it has no bounds so it keeps subtracting until I lift my finger off space.

Comment: `jumpVelocity += 1` is addition